# PrimePush with clustering

Tags: primefaces

We are using primepush in order to push messages to clients.

Currently we have 3 servers that can make the primepush event:

The code which exists on 3 servers:

```
EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();            
eventBus.publish("/example", new FacesMessage(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(message, StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml("")));
```

My question is how can we make sure this primepush will be send to clients on all servers?

Environment details: 
Tomcat 7.0.35 
Primefaces 5.1

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

That is not PrimeFaces push related but Atmosphere, the framework the is behind it. Check [their documentation](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Configuring-Atmosphere-for-the-Cloud) and pick one that suites you